# Is this entry in error_log a security issue? - File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/files

Tags: linux, security

Is it strange to see entries such as the one below in an `error_log`?

```
[Sat Dec 08 18:10:16 2012] [error] [client 66.249.76.---] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/files
```

My understanding was that `File does not exist:` basically means a 404?

Why would an unknown ip try to be accesing `/usr/local/apache/htdocs/files` ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a Google IP address, and they're probably trying to access it because something was there at some point in the past. Your web server sent them a 404, since there is nothing there now.

It is kind of unusual that you didn't provide redirects when you reorganized your site; typically this is done for search engine optimization purposes.

Comment: No webpages have moved or changed their location though, seems quite strange? Should all sites have a standard 404 not found page?

Comment: You might find it more useful to look at your access log and see what it was that Google actually requested.